# Adding multiple effects to animation using storyboard using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am having trouble adding multiple effects within an animation sequence in WPF. I have multiple rectangles arranged within a grid and the way the animation effect is to work is in the following order:

1. By default, the user sees the grid such that every cell is bounded by a silver border on a black canvas, the color of the rectangle within each cell could be transparent/black.
2. On mouse hover, the rectangle in the cell changes its stroke and fill to green.
3. On exiting the mouse over, the previous cell slowly changes color to its default state before the mouse hover.

I was able to do the animation effect for just the stroke color but not combine it with the fill properties. Here is the code snippet for creating the rectangles within the grid:

```
            Style cellStyle = PrepareAnimationStyle();
            foreach (string label in rowHeaders)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < numOfCols; n++)
                    grid.Children.Add(new Rectangle()
                    {
                        Stroke = Brushes.Silver,
                        StrokeThickness = 2,
                        Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
                        Height = cellSize,
                        Width = cellSize,
                        Style = cellstyle
                    });
            }
```

And here is the code that sets the animation (still in progress, can't make it work as required):

```
Style PrepareAnimationStyle()
{
    Trigger animTrigger = new Trigger();
    animTrigger.Property = ContentElement.IsMouseOverProperty;
    animTrigger.Value = true;

    System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation toGreen = new          System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
    toGreen.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
    System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation toTransparent = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(Colors.Transparent, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation toSilver = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(Colors.Silver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard sbEnter = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();
    //Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(toGreen, new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(toGreen, new PropertyPath("(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));
    sbEnter.Children.Add(toGreen);

    /*Storyboard sbFill = new Storyboard();
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(toGreen, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
    sbFill.Children.Add(toSilver);

    Storyboard sbFillEmpty = new Storyboard();
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(toTransparent, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
    sbFillEmpty.Children.Add(toSilver);*/

    Storyboard sbExit = new Storyboard();
    //Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(toSilver, new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(toTransparent, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
    sbExit.Children.Add(toSilver);

    animTrigger.EnterActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbEnter });
    //animTrigger.EnterActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbFill });
    //animTrigger.EnterActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbFillEmpty });
    animTrigger.ExitActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbExit });

    Style cellStyle = new Style();
    cellStyle.Triggers.Add(animTrigger);

    return cellStyle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
    Style PrepareAnimationStyle()
    {
        Trigger animTrigger = new Trigger();
        animTrigger.Property = FrameworkElement.IsMouseOverProperty;
        animTrigger.Value = true;

        ColorAnimation strokeToGreen = new ColorAnimation((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
        ColorAnimation strokeToSilver = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Silver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        ColorAnimation fillToGreen = new ColorAnimation((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
        ColorAnimation fillToTransparent = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Transparent, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        Storyboard sbEnter = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(strokeToGreen, new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fillToGreen, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
        sbEnter.Children.Add(strokeToGreen);
        sbEnter.Children.Add(fillToGreen);

        Storyboard sbExit = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(strokeToSilver, new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fillToTransparent, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
        sbExit.Children.Add(strokeToSilver);
        sbExit.Children.Add(fillToTransparent);

        animTrigger.EnterActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbEnter });
        animTrigger.ExitActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbExit });

        Style cellStyle = new Style();
        cellStyle.Triggers.Add(animTrigger);

        return cellStyle;
    }
```

in order to make it work properly make sure to set a fill and stroke while you add the cell

example

```
        Style cellStyle = PrepareAnimationStyle(); //this line is out side of the cell loop
        ....
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver);
        rect.Style = cellStyle;
```